# Wordpress admin - live post preview in iframe

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe, admin, preview

My goal is to show live preview in custom post type edit form in Wordpress admin. I got to the point, where I can successfully display iframe with preview next to meta / ACF fields in post edit form as seen on this wireframe:

[image]

When I click on "Preview Changes" button, iframe content is refreshed successfully. But I want to do it automatically after some of ACF fields are changed. So i try to simulate click on this button with jQuery:

```
$('input, select', $('#acf-group_609ca87c411ae')).on('change', function() {
      $('a.preview').click();
});
```

But when I do this, the behaviour is completely different: instead of refreshing iframe, whole page is refreshed with message: Post updated.

I feel I'm so close to make this live preview work but I'm stuck on this simple simulation of click for several hours. Could you help me?

EDIT: Forget the iframe thing - if you are wordpress programmer, simply open WP admin, on edit post screen and try to simulate click on "Preview changes" button programatically. If you get the same behaviour as clicking on it - post me the javascript here. Thank you!

Comment: Haven't used Wordpress in a while so just guessing here. You can look into the function that is triggered by the click of the Preview Changes button and use that code to refresh the iframe directly instead of calling the click event on the button.

Comment: I tried calling the code directly but with no success. It seems that I need to call multiple consequent triggers but I haven't found which ones and in what order exactly...

Comment: Okay, in that case, you might have to figure that part out as I don't see any other way to trigger a button programmatically

Answer (score -1):

You're triggering a click which is going to reload the page. Its the default behaviour.
If you dont want the link to proceed then you need to stop the event from triggering. You could try:

```
//This should trigger the click but prevent the default behaviour of reloading the page
//Untested
$('input, select', $('#acf-group_609ca87c411ae')).on('change', function() {
  $('a.preview').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code does nothing because it just sets the event handler. But even when i trigger the click after it, the page is refreshed completely:

`$('a.preview').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  }).click();`

Comment: So your saying in effect that you want to simulate the click on that element so that everything it does happens, it just doesn't refresh the page. As though it were done via ajax?

Comment: When I click on this button, it does not behave as standard link. There seem to be some handler that cause different behaviour, something like submitting edit form to target window. I want simply simulate with Javascript the same behaviour as clicking on this button manually. DO THE SAME THING. I looked to wordpress core javascript for these event handlers and tried to copy some of it to my code but with no success. It seems that there are multiple triggers that need to be fired in specific order for this behaviour to happen...